# Same base url for categories and products in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

is it possible to have the same base url for categories and products in woocommerce? At the moment it's giving my category page an 404 but products working fine.

What i'm trying to do is that both have the base "shop" 
Categories: demo.com/shop/category/ 
Products: demo.com/shop/category/product-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution could be this one [Permalinks for Woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291018/permalinks-for-woocommerce-categories-and-subcategories)

Try to add this in your functions.php

```
function wpse_291143_generate_taxonomy_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $base = "shop";

    $rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false ));

    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $term_children = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'parent' => intval($term->term_id),
            'hide_empty' => false
            )
        );
        if($term_children) {
            foreach ( $term_children as $term_child ) {
                $rules[$base . '/' . $term->slug . '/' . $term_child->slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_child->slug;
            }
        }
    }

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'wpse_291143_generate_taxonomy_rewrite_rules');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73333483/6835106

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'shop/([^/]*?)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'shop/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
} );
```

add this code to functions.php