# How can I have shop base and product base the same in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I am trying to have the same shop base and the same product base at the same time.
The format I am trying to have is:

> website.com/shop/shoes/blue-suede-shoes/

I came across this code that makes it work so far with just a small glitch:

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules ) {
    $new_rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
        'post_type'  => 'product',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        $siteurl = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_slug = $term->slug;
            $baseterm = str_replace( $siteurl, '', get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ) );
            // rules for a specific category
            $new_rules[$baseterm .'?$'] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug;
            // rules for a category pagination
            $new_rules[$baseterm . '/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' ] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug . '&paged=$matches[1]';
            $new_rules[$baseterm.'(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug . '&feed=$matches[1]';
        }
    }

    return $new_rules + $rules;
} );

function imp_create_term() {
    flush_rewrite_rules(false);;
}
add_action( 'create_term', 'imp_create_term' );
```

Every single path works as desired, except when I try to open:

> website.com/shop/shoes/page/2
>   which returns a page not found error

this path works well tough:

> website.com/shop/page/2

**What am I missing? Does WP interprets "page" as a subcategory?**
How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Cant you just do this with permalinks under settings?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.. not even to make it so far..

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as answer so I can include a screenshot for you.

1) Go to yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

2) Under Product Permalinks select Shop Base with Category. This will work for product level.

[image: woocommerce example]

3) Set the product category base to something like /shop/product-category

[WC Permalink Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/permalinks/)

Don't forget to remove your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this little coed snippets in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'shop/([^/]*?)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'shop/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
} );
```